# rotate/pivot a table from long to wide in pandas and create column of difference between previous columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I have a table that looks like this:

`> data = {'index':[0,1,2,3],'column_names':['foo_1','foo_2','bar_1','bar_2'], 'Totals':[1050,400,450,300]}`

and I want to do three things:

1. Pivot each row in the 'column name' column to an actual column name.
2. Create an additional column whose values are the difference of the values of ('foo_1' and 'foo_2') and ('bar_1' and 'bar_2')
3. This also needs to be a dataframe object that looks like this:
   `data_t = {'foo_1':[1050],'foo_2':[400],'Foo % Diff':[650],'bar_1':[450],'bar_2':[300],'Bar % Diff':[150]}`

Really would appreciate how to do this and explanations.

Comment: What have you tried? Also please take a look at how to [provide reproducible sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391) on this site.

Comment: @StargazingFish please accept one of the answers as solution by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to `.groupby` to get the difference with `diff().abs()` in `s1`
2. Then, you need to `.groupby` to get the name of the total columns in `s2` and `concat` s1 and s2 together.
3. From there, `append` the results of `s1` and `s2` to the dataframe and use `.T` to transpose the dataframe *after* setting the index to `column_names`, so values in `column_names` show up as the column headers instead of being in the first row, which is what would happen without `.set_index()`:

---

```
data = {'column_names':['foo_1','foo_2','bar_1','bar_2'], 'Totals':[1050,400,450,300]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
s = df['column_names'].str.split('_').str[0]
s1 = df.groupby(s)['Totals'].diff().abs()
s2 = df.groupby(s)['column_names'].apply(lambda x: x.str.split('_').str[0] + '__% Diff')
df = (df.append(pd.concat([s1,s2], axis=1).dropna())
      .sort_values('column_names').set_index('column_names').T)
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('__', ' ') # the column name was chosen carefully to preserve order and then you can simply replace __ with a space
df
Out[1]: 
column_names  bar_1  bar_2  bar % Diff   foo_1  foo_2  foo % Diff
Totals        450.0  300.0       150.0  1050.0  400.0       650.0
```

---

Or, if you are looking for the percentage change with `pct_change()`:

```
data = {'column_names':['foo_1','foo_2','bar_1','bar_2'], 'Totals':[1050,400,450,300]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
s = df['column_names'].str.split('_').str[0]
s1 = df.groupby(s)['Totals'].apply(lambda x: x.pct_change())
s2 = df.groupby(s)['column_names'].apply(lambda x: x.str.split('_').str[0] + '__% Diff')
df = (df.append(pd.concat([s1,s2], axis=1).dropna())
      .sort_values('column_names').set_index('column_names').T)
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('__', ' ') # the column name was chosen carefully to preserve order and then you can simply replace __ with a space
df
Out[2]: 
column_names  bar_1  bar_2  bar % Diff   foo_1  foo_2  foo % Diff
Totals        450.0  300.0   -0.333333  1050.0  400.0   -0.619048
```